# How to solve my pagination in yii?

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I have some problems with my pagination.
Here is my code.

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model=new Order;
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $total = Order::model()->count($criteria);
    $pages = new CPagination($total);
    $pages->setPageSize(Yii::app()->params['listPerPage']);
    $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
    // $posts = konsumen::model()->findAll($criteria);


    $this->render('index',
        array('model'=>$model,
                // 'list'=>$posts,
                'pages' => $pages,
                'item_count'=>$total,
                'page_size'=>Yii::app()->params['listPerPage'],)) ;
}
```

View:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM order where date between '$date_first' and '$date_last' and status $status order by id desc";
$list = DetailPesanan::model()->findAllBySql("$result"); 
if($list)
{
?>
<div class="tablebx" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;"><!-- End div class="pagecon" --> 

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="tablebx_topbg">
            <td><?php echo Yii::t('consumen','No.');?></td> 
            <td><?php echo Yii::t('consumen','Date');?></td>
            <td><?php echo Yii::t('consumen','Quantity');?></td>
            <td><?php echo Yii::t('consumen','Debt');?></td>
            <td><?php echo Yii::t('consumen','Profit');?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        if(isset($_REQUEST['page']))
        {
            $i=($pages->pageSize*$_REQUEST['page'])-9;
        }
        else
        {
            $i=1;
        }
        $cls="even";
        ?>

        <?php

        foreach($list as $list_1)

        {
        ?>
            <tr class=<?php echo $cls;?>>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $list_1->date ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rp=number_format($list_1->quantity, 0, ',', '.') ?> Pcs</td>
            <td>Rp. <?php echo $rp=number_format($list_1->debt, 0, ',', '.') ?></td>
            <td>Rp. <?php echo $rp=number_format($list_1->profit, 0, ',', '.') ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if($cls=="even")
            {
                $cls="odd" ;
            }
            else
            {
                $cls="even"; 
            }
            $i++; 
        } 
        ?>                           
    </table>

    <div class="pagecon">
            <?php                                          
              $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
              'currentPage'=>$pages->getCurrentPage(),
              'itemCount'=>$item_count,
              'pageSize'=>$page_size,
              'maxButtonCount'=>5,
              //'nextPageLabel'=>'My text >',
              'header'=>'',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pages'),
            ));?>
    </div> <!-- END div class="pagecon" 2 -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div> <!-- END div class="tablebx" -->
<?php 
}
else
{
    echo '<div class="listhdg" align="center">'.Yii::t('consument','data cannot found').'</div>';  
}?>
```

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: helloo ?? can anyone help me ?

Comment: my pagination is not working @eskimo

Comment: Not working as in you get a PHP error? It doesn't go to the other pages? It causes the users computer to spontaneously combust? Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what will you do if you in my position ? @eskimo